# How to deserialize an object with GSON where data doesn't have a member/parameter name?

Tags: java, json, gson

an API

```
@GET("api/v1/depth")
Call<OrderBook> getOrderBook(@Query("symbol") String paramString, @Query("limit") int limit);
```

gives this response:

```
{
    "lastUpdateId": 1027024,
    "bids": [
        [
            "4.00000000",
            "431.00000000", []
        ]
    ],
    "asks": [
        [
            "4.00000200",
            "12.00000000", []
        ]
    ]
}
```

to deserialize the response, jsonschema2pojo.org created the class **OrderBook** as follows:

```
public class OrderBook {

@SerializedName("lastUpdateId")
public Long lastUpdateId;

@SerializedName("bids")
public List<List<String>> bids = null;

@SerializedName("asks")
public List<List<String>> asks = null;

}
```

However, you can see that `List<List<String>>` is not correct.

It should be something akin to `List<List<String, String, List<Void>>>`

However, without member names, that doesn't seem possible. It would be great if GSON had annotation that identified position instead of name. https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/package-summary.html but such an annotation doesn't exist.

What is the correct way to obtain a POJO from such a minimalist response ?

Comment: There's no such thing as a `List<X,Y,Z>`. `List` has only one generic variable. You probably need something like `List<Object>`, or to write your own custom deserializer.

Comment: You need to give us all of different cases of your response to design exact POJO mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it would be better if you'd include [the original source](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#order-book) of the given payload.
It would give at least some more hints on what's encoded in the payload:

```js
{
  "lastUpdateId": 1027024,
  "bids": [
    [
      "4.00000000",     // PRICE
      "431.00000000",   // QTY
      []                // Ignore.
    ]
  ],
  "asks": [
    [
      "4.00000200",
      "12.00000000",
      []
    ]
  ]
}
```

Next, jsonschema2pojo generates too naive mappings, and it's unable to create type adapters that are usually the only tool that can work with such payloads.
For example:

The following mapping can be easily deserialized with Java Reflection, and since you're probably not going to change its state, you can make all its fields `final`.

```java
final class Order {

    final long lastUpdateId = Long.valueOf(0); // if `0`, then javac inlines 0 everywhere
                                               // so we're kind of cheating
    final List<PriceAndQuantity> bids = null;
    final List<PriceAndQuantity> asks = null;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("lastUpdateId", lastUpdateId)
                .add("bids", bids)
                .add("asks", asks)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

The following object requires a slightly another way of instantiating a deserialized value.
It *could* lack a constructor as well as the previous mapping does (requires a stream to a special structure JSON tree conversion, and then converted with Java Reflection), but it's easier just to instantiate it by hand.

```java
final class PriceAndQuantity {

    final double price;
    final double quantity;

    private PriceAndQuantity(final double price, final double quantity) {
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    static PriceAndQuantity of(final double price, final double quantity) {
        return new PriceAndQuantity(price, quantity);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MoreObjects.toStringHelper(this)
                .add("price", price)
                .add("quantity", quantity)
                .toString();
    }

}
```

Now, here is how you can tell Gson the above class instance can be deserialized from such a JSON stream.

```java
final class PriceAndQuantityTypeAdapter
        extends TypeAdapter<PriceAndQuantity> {

    private static final TypeAdapter<PriceAndQuantity> instance = new PriceAndQuantityTypeAdapter()
            .nullSafe();

    private PriceAndQuantityTypeAdapter() {
    }

    static TypeAdapter<PriceAndQuantity> get() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final PriceAndQuantity value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public PriceAndQuantity read(final JsonReader in)
            throws IOException {
        in.beginArray();
        final double price = in.nextDouble(); // Indicated as PRICE in the documentation
        final double quantity = in.nextDouble(); // Indicated as QTY in the documentation
        // BEGIN alternative to in.skipValue()
        // JsonReader.skipValue consumes any JSON literal,
        // but here we assert a sequence of [ and ] explicitly
        in.beginArray();
        in.endArray();
        // END alternative to in.skipValue()
        in.endArray();
        return PriceAndQuantity.of(price, quantity);
    }

}
```

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(PriceAndQuantity.class, PriceAndQuantityTypeAdapter.get())
        .create();

public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException {
    // It just readers the JSON you've put in the question from a resource package
    try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = Resources.getPackageResourceJsonReader(Q50317182.class, "response.json") ) {
        final Order order = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Order.class);
        System.out.println(order);
    }
}
```

Here is a sample output:

> Order{lastUpdateId=1027024, bids=[PriceAndQuantity{price=4.0, quantity=431.0}], asks=[PriceAndQuantity{price=4.000002, quantity=12.0}]}

Comment: quick tip for anyone wanting to use this with Retrofit; the code will be something like `new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(PriceAndQuantity.class, PriceAndQuantityTypeAdapter.get()).create()))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `List<List<String>>` as the **third** index of the **inner list** is an **array/list**, not a **String**.

So, in your case you should use **`List<List<Object>>`**

Comment: this works, but it means having to cast the object fields